# Is it safe to display an OAuth Access Token?

Tags: facebook, security, facebook-graph-api, oauth

Are there security concerns with displaying an access token my OAuth 2.0 app has obtained? Maybe not necessarily display, but even echo it to a website's source code where it's essentially "findable" by the user. Assume everything is HTTPS.

Example: I have a website where I want to allow people to log in with Facebook. Once they log in, I get an FB API access token back from an identity provider or the Facebook PHP SDK. This token is tied to the user that just logged in. I want to make the user feel at home by displaying their profile picture, is it safe to render some HTML similar to the following?

```
<img src='https://graph.facebook.com/me/picture?access_token=USERS_ACCESS_TOKEN'>
```

*Edit:*
I know there are other options for displaying a profile picture, I'm not necessarily asking for a better way to do that. I'm more interested in the security that needs to be taken with these access tokens. Most of the resources I've seen don't seem to mention anything about it.

Comment: You should never need to output the access token in the source code. Your example of getting a profile image doesn’t need it, and so far you have not described any other specific use case where that would be a requirement. If you want to make client-side API calls, then use the JS SDK, and let that handle the token.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The access token should have a minimal set of permissions associated with it, i.e. just enough to actually display the users picture. In that case there's no increased risk wrt. XSS attacks since each solution to display the picture would involve the same risks in the case that an attacker manages to steal the session cookie and/or the token.

Only when the access token has additional permissions associated with it that are not used as a part of your front-end it would be a less preferred from a security standpoint to present it in the front-end.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This is along the lines of what I was thinking, whether the token is contained in a JS object or is actually somewhere on the DOM, the only thing we're really worried about is some kind of XSS attack (other than something like over-the-shoulder viewing). I'm not sure about how the JS SDKs tend to take care of these tokens, but I have to assume if someone has access to the scripts they can access the tokens.

Comment: Although I suppose having an `<img>` or `<a>` tag with the token makes the user more likely to do something like right-click and save image as or send the link to someone else. So at least inside the JS is more secure than that, hadn't thought about that until just now.

Comment: I would not label that  more secure, but more obscure indeed, i.e. less convenient to strip it out or to save it somewhere by accident but certainly still feasible for a determined attacker.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if the OAuth token is tied to the user session then there is nothing simpler for the attacker to steal users cookie (for instance by XSS) and use it together with the access token to make some actions on his FB on behalf of his account in your app. I would say rule of thumb in security related stuff is to disclose only the information you really have to and nothing else.

Answer (score -1):

Ahh i see what you're doing. Instead of the oauth token do this: `http://graph.facebook.com/1477079525902964/picture` and ta-da

Comment: I maybe should have clarified this more in the question (I will edit), but I'm not necessarily looking for how to display the profile picture. I know there are a few different ways to do it, I was more curious about the security precautions that need to be taken with access tokens. Do you have a good resource showing that they shouldn't be rendered in plain text?

Comment: From what i see here there are a couple of them that could be a security concern: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.5 (ads_management, user_photos, publish_actions) i think the rule of thumb is just dont. No one wants any liability. If its on the page i can create a XSS attack to target your page and fish them out of the html.